# How to get the x,y coordinates of the turtle?

Tags: coffeescript, turtle-graphics

In [Pencil Code](http://pencilcode.net), how to get the relative x,y coordinates of the default turtle?
Why does the following code not work (it returns "0,0")?

```
fd 100
write getxy()
```

How to wait for the turtle to finish moving before calling getxy()?

Answer (score 0):

Use `done(fn)`. It calls the callback fn after all animation.